# What is the current state of health of Philosophy SE?

Tags: discussion

I'm asking this question on account of the recent meta post:

[Is everything OK at Stack Exchange now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356705/is-everything-ok-at-stack-exchange-now)

and in continuance of the dialog in :

[What's going on with our lack of nominations?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/whats-going-on-with-our-lack-of-nominations)

which ultimately stems from my own question:

[Friends, Are We Not Philosophers: Is This Place a Bazaar or a Cathedral?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5194/friends-are-we-not-philosophers-is-this-place-a-bazaar-or-a-cathedral)

Comment: Just checked the analytics...it seems we have less views with comparable visits of registered users and slightly higher levels of new users compared to the last two years. Just adding this as a comment here since many users do not have access to these tools.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Does a slightly elevated blood pressure and slightly depressed pulse adequately speak to the health of the persistently vegetative? Philosophical activity without metaphilosophical activity betrays a certain kind of brain death.